# Iterate over tuple of functors in c++11

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, variadic-templates, template-meta-programming

I have a `std::tuple` of functors (of unknown arity) that are expected to all return the same type, so something like:

```
typedef functor std::function<bool()>;
std::tuple<functor, functor, functor...> functors;
```

I'd like to iterate over functors, evaluating each member until I find one that succeeds, otherwise failure.  How can I achieve this in c++11?

Comment: Please post what you have tried.

Comment: strictly C++11? No C++14?

Comment: @max66 correct unfortunately

Comment: @R Sahu I haven't tried much, tried a little pattern matching to get the head and tail of the tuple, but didn't have much luck.  There's tuple_cat to merge tuples but nothing to split them nicely so it's tricky.

Comment: A template function that takes `int index` template parameter, alongside the tuple, and does `return get<index>(t)() || ThisFunction<index+1>(t);` Plus an overload SFINAE-enabled for the case of `index >= tuple_size<T>::value` and returning `false` unconditionally. Something like that.

Comment: Can functors have different arity? How are functor's arguments passed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not particularly creative but...

If you create a `foo()` function as follows

```
template <typename ... Args>
bool foo (std::tuple<Args...> const & tf)
 { return bar<0>(tf); }
```

that call, starting with template index 0, the following couple of template (SFINAE enabled/disabled) alternative functions

```
template <std::size_t I, typename ... Args>
typename std::enable_if<(I >= sizeof...(Args)), bool>::type
   bar (std::tuple<Args...> const &)
 { return false; }

template <std::size_t I, typename ... Args>
typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof...(Args)), bool>::type
   bar (std::tuple<Args...> const & tf)
 { return baz(std::get<I>(tf)) || bar<I+1U>(tf); }
```

and an additional `baz()` function to call single functors

```
bool baz (functor const & f)
 { return f(); }
```

I suppose you can obtain what do you want.

The following is a full working example

```
#include <tuple>
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>

using functor = std::function<bool()>;

bool baz (functor const & f)
 { return f(); }

template <std::size_t I, typename ... Args>
typename std::enable_if<(I >= sizeof...(Args)), bool>::type
   bar (std::tuple<Args...> const &)
 { return false; }

template <std::size_t I, typename ... Args>
typename std::enable_if<(I < sizeof...(Args)), bool>::type
   bar (std::tuple<Args...> const & tf)
 { return baz(std::get<I>(tf)) || bar<I+1U>(tf); }

template <typename ... Args>
bool foo (std::tuple<Args...> const & tf)
 { return bar<0>(tf); }

bool f0 () { std::cout << "f0 "; return false; }
bool f1 () { std::cout << "f1 "; return false; }
bool f2 () { std::cout << "f2 "; return false; }
bool f3 () { std::cout << "f3 "; return false; }
bool f4 () { std::cout << "f4 "; return true; }
bool f5 () { std::cout << "f5 "; return false; }
bool f6 () { std::cout << "f6 "; return false; }
bool f7 () { std::cout << "f7 "; return false; }
bool f8 () { std::cout << "f8 "; return false; }
bool f9 () { std::cout << "f9 "; return false; }

int main ()
 {
   auto tf = std::make_tuple(f0, f1, f2, f3, f4, f5, f6, f7, f8, f9);

   foo(tf);
 }
```

Obviously you can avoid the use of `baz()` and simply call the functors as follows

```
 return std::get<I>(tf)() || bar<I+1U>(tf);
```

but you loose a check over the `Args...` types.

Comment: Or replace `std::tuple` with `std::vector` and remove all that unnecessary code

Comment: @Slava - Yes, but so isn't funny :-( (I'm joking and I'm agree: if the OP can, the use a std::vector, instead of a std::tuple, is greatly preferable).

Answer (score -1):

Just use proper container - `std::vector` instead of `std::tuple`:

```
using functor = std::function<bool()>;
using functors = std::vector<functor>;
```

and I thing it is pretty obvious how to iterate over `std::vector`

Comment: I was a little inaccurate, the parsers all return "compatible" types so that they can be promoted to some type, but they're not necessarily exactly the same type.   Plus I want to use tuple to keep thing statically allocated.

Comment: Then if you read documentation on `std::tuple_cat` http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/tuple_cat  it gives you exact example on how to iterate over tuple